# Database Object for Oracle Error messages

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to know the oracle objects which contain the predefined error messages along with the error code ,plz help me to get the database objects

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand the question.  If you are asking whether there is a data dictionary table that has the error code and error message for every error, there is no such table.  You could potentially call the `SQLERRM` function for every possible error code and build such a table yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the error messages you have had:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the ORA-nnnnn type messages? If so, these I beleive are not held in database tables, but in OS files under Oracle_HOME as message files (for each language). There is (on UNIX/LInux at least) a utility called "oerr" which you run as "oerr ora 1301" and it will give you the message for the given code in the lanagues according to your LOCALE/settings. If you want to get all the messages, you can get these from the ORacle manuals, e.g.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/toc.htm